# do we have $:\left\Vert Q^{n+1}x\right\Vert \leq \varepsilon \left\Vert Q^{n}x\right\Vert $ for all $x\in \mathcal{H}$ for a quasi-nilpotent operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and let $Q$ be a bounded
quasi-nilpotent operator on $\mathcal{H}$.

I'm trying to prove that for every$\ \varepsilon >0,$ there is some $n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
,$ such that $:\left\Vert Q^{n+1}x\right\Vert \leq \varepsilon \left\Vert
Q^{n}x\right\Vert $ for all $x\in \mathcal{H}$.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this operator be a counter example? Define $T$ on $H=l^2$ as
$$
Tx =(0, \frac{x_1}{2^1}, x_2, \frac{x_3}{2^3}, x_4, \dots ).
$$

Comment: I will see, thank you.

Comment: I think it is, I will check it. Thank you